# Android Studio not opening after initial splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio does not open after the initial splash screen.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you've set JAVA_HOME in your classpath as required

Comment: done that but still getting same

Comment: As far as I know, this should only be happening if either the JAVA_HOME is not set to the java directory or the `class` path is not set to the java/bin directory. But even those should be giving you an error corresponding to it.

Comment: What's your doubt? Be clearer.

Comment: Not clear, please explain your problem specifically, or give more details into the problem

Answer (score -2):

i was working on ionic, installed Android SDK and set up JDK_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME, then i wanted to install Android studio and I got the issue.
my coworker installed Android studio too and never worked on ionic, so he don't get set up those paths.
so i remove those paths and work fine :)